# How to console.log the state after it is updated in React in a second callback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, setstate, react-state

I want to `console.log()` the `searchActive` state before and after it is updated. Initially its value is `false`. When I put the second `console.log` after the `setSearchActive` in a normal order, it runs before the state is updated so both `console.log`s return `false`. Thus, I put the second one in a callback function of state updater, however, I get an error which says **"Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect()"**. and the second log never runs. How can I fix this issue?

```
    function startSearch (e) {
        let searchresult = document.querySelector('.search-result');

        if(!searchActive&&e.target.value!==null){
            searchresult.classList.add('search-active');
            console.log(searchActive);
            setSearchActive(true,()=>{
                console.log(searchActive);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use `useEffect` hook for triggering side effects, just like `console.log()` - [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Probably `useEffect(() => console.log('searchActive'), [searchActive])` is the one what you are looking for.

Comment: Else you can just check your state in react devtools.

Comment: @norbitrial Thanks. That solves the problem partially. Now, how can I prevent useEffect from getting called before the state changes when the page is initially loaded ?